# Adding a custom made JPanel from a separate class file in another JPanel on runtime

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, subclass

I have a custom made JPanel made in a separate class file with some parameters, named itemCard and **I am trying to add an instance of it by giving values in the parameters in another jpanel(contentAreaPane) in another jframe(mainPage.java) class file on the actionPerformed event of a button (jButton1)**

`itemCard.java`

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import Resources.colors.MaterialColor;
import Resources.fonts.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Aditya
 */
public class itemCard extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form itemCard
     */

    public String name,price,retailer, prodID;

    /**
     * Takes four parameters, first is product ID which is a String, second is product
     * name which is a String, third is price which is a String,
     *  fourth is retailer name which is a String.
     */
    public itemCard(String prodID, String productName, String price, String retailer) {
        this.name = productName;
        this.price = price;
        this.retailer = retailer;
        this.prodID = prodID;


        initComponents();


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        imageIconHolder = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        detailPane = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        priceTag = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(MaterialColor.BLUE_200, 2, true));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 300));
        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseExited(evt);
            }
        });
        setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        imageIconHolder.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        imageIconHolder.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        imageIconHolder.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 200));
        imageIconHolder.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 200));
        imageIconHolder.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 200));
        add(imageIconHolder, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 250, 200));

        detailPane.setBackground(MaterialColor.LIGHTBLUE_800);
        detailPane.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        priceTag.setBackground(MaterialColor.PURPLE_800);
        priceTag.setFont(Montserrat.REGULAR.deriveFont(25f));
        priceTag.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        priceTag.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        priceTag.setText(price);
        priceTag.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        priceTag.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 100));
        priceTag.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 100));
        priceTag.setOpaque(true);
        priceTag.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 100));
        detailPane.add(priceTag, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 70, 100));

        jScrollPane2.setBorder(null);
        jScrollPane2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jScrollPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        jScrollPane2.setEnabled(false);
        jScrollPane2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(180, 100));

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setBackground(MaterialColor.DEEPPURPLE_700);
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setFont(Roboto.THIN.deriveFont(20f)
        );
        jTextArea1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setText(((name.length()>51)?(name.substring(0, 48)+"...") : (name)) +"\n"+ ((retailer.length()>14)?(retailer.substring(0, 14)+"...") : (retailer)));
        jTextArea1.setToolTipText(name+"\n"+retailer);
        jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jTextArea1.setBorder(null);
        jTextArea1.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(7, 5, 7, 5));
        jTextArea1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        detailPane.add(jScrollPane2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 0, 180, 100));

        add(detailPane, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 200, 250, 100));
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        this.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(MaterialColor.BLUE_400, 3, true));
        detailPane.setBackground(MaterialColor.LIGHTBLUE_900);
    }                                 

    private void formMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
        this.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(MaterialColor.BLUE_200, 2, true));
        detailPane.setBackground(MaterialColor.LIGHTBLUE_800);
    }                                

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel detailPane;
    private javax.swing.JLabel imageIconHolder;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel priceTag;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

and here's the actionperformed event listener of my button:

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            JPanel itemcard = new itemCard("123456789AB","Inspiron 7567 Intel Core i5 DELL Laptop","68K","CloudTail Pvt. Ltd.");
            contentAreaPane.add(itemcard);
            contentAreaPane.revalidate();
            contentAreaPane.repaint();



        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, this isn't working, that is no new itemCard JPanel gets created and showed in contentAreaPane JPanel when clicked on jButton1 and is giving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1152)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:436)
at AppFrames.mainPage.jButton1ActionPerformed(mainPage.java:887)
at AppFrames.mainPage$31.actionPerformed(mainPage.java:619)
```

How I can resolve it?

Comment: Don't use AbsoluteLayout. It is expecting you to provide the size/location of the panel. That is NOT a real layout manager. A Real layout manager will set the size/location of the panel based on the rules of the layout manager. Don't use the IDE to generate your code. Instead, rRead the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples to get you started. Learn to build your GUIs manually.

Comment: So if I specify the size a nd location of the panel, will it work?

Comment: I know its a good practice to make GUIs manually, but as I have limited number of days to work on this project (Shopping cart app), and I have still not done the coding for database yet, which is worth more time spending, so I thought its ok to buildit with an IDE

Comment: 1) You missed the whole point of my comment. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size/location of a component. If you do it how do you know that the size/location should be? You would just be guessing. The rules should be built into the layout manager. 2) If you want to know if it will work, then try it.

Comment: @camickr Thanks a lot! Flow Layout is the Layout which fits my needs best, without which I would have been doing all that spacing manually.

Comment: PS: I also tried absolute positioning, as you pointed out the mistake in @ControlAltDel 's answer's comment section, and it also worked with this piece of code: `containerPanel.add(PaneltobeAdded, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(X pos, Y pos, width, height));`

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for Container, it lists these exceptions:

```
IllegalArgumentException - if index is invalid; if comp is a child of this container, the valid range is [-1, getComponentCount()-1]; if component is not a child of this container, the valid range is [-1, getComponentCount()]
IllegalArgumentException - if comp is an ancestor of this container
IllegalArgumentException - if adding a window to a container
```

I think you must be getting this on condition 2 or 3

Comment: The problem is the AbsoluteLayout expects a constraint to be provided. Look at the code generated by the IDE. The add(...) method uses an AbsoluteConstraints object to specify the layout information.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for clarifying that!